# Limits in multivariable functions

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I tried to evaluate this limit but I can't see any limited function here (the limit exists).

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$

Thank you.

Comment: You don't solve a limit, but you evaluate or compute it.

Comment: My bad, sorry :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try $y=kx^2$ and show that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Exactly, it does exist, but how do I evaluate it?

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand the question, the limit does not exist at all, since for different $k$, the limit is different.

Comment: @ZainPatel and Vinicius, no the limit does not exist. The function equals $0$ on the axes, hence if the limit exists, it is $0.$ Try what Eclipse said to see this can't be true.

Comment: @EclipseSun Not sure why you have the $k$ there.

Comment: There might be a typo in my textbook, because the question asked me to evaluate it (with the information that it exists) :/, and WolframAlpha returns 0 as an answer.... thank you!!

Comment: @zhw. Of course one can fixed $k=1$, for example.

Comment: You don't even need $k$, try to evaluate it along the curve $(t, t^2)$ and the curve $(0, t)$: you will get different results.

Comment: @zhw: There is a very good reason for the $k$, for it yields a family of different limits as we approach $(0,0)$ along various parabolas..

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$$, taking $y=mx^2$
 ,we have,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{2mx^4}{x^4 + m^2x^4}$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{2m}{1 + m^2}=\frac{2m}{1 + m^2}$$, which shows that limit depends upon the $m$ and changes with value of $m$ . Hence limit does not exist.